# How Should I Choose A Multi-Vitamin Designed for Men?

Tags: supplements, vitamins

How should I choose a multi-vitamin as a man? Should I just try and get the most potency/per dollar product? Are there any well known generally accepted superior brands?

Comment: I edited your question to make it less subjective.  Please click `edit(0)` to review my edit and accept it if you think my edit will improve your question and help keep it from getting closed.

Comment: @jmort253 Good edit. Cheers.

Comment: Off topic per new site rules in the [FAQ].

Comment: This is now deemed as off-topic per the [FAQ](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq) and will be closed. Only nutrition questions related to fitness are on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your age. How old you are can determine what things you need to focus on. Men's formulas have varying amounts of ingredients (like small amounts of iron). Some increase certain ingredients to help focus on specific areas (memory, prostate, cholesterol etc). My suggestion is you get a physical and talk to your doctor about the results and discuss what you should be taking.

Otherwise, just grab a centrum for men.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against getting the highest potency for the dollar. Quality matters.

Higher quality supplements tend to be better absorbed and utilized by the body. Mega dozes of cheap supplements generally have a high percent pass through unused.

In addition, some research suggests unnatural forms of supplements may not provide the same benefits or may even be harmful.

I personally buy New Chapter which is very expensive. It's actually made from cultured and fermented real foods and is highly absorbable even though cheaper brands may provide higher dozes.